# Using split Function in java with delimiter as '|' character(OR symbol)

Tags: java, regex, string

Here If I am given a string `aaaa|bbb`, I want output as aaaa and bbb. If I use `string.split("|")` It returns each character of the string as separate Array of strings like

```
output[0]="a",output[1]="a",output[2]="a",output[3]="a",output[4]="a",output[5]="|",output[6]="b",output[&]="b",output[0]="b"
```

But I want it as `output[0]=aaaa, output[1]=bbb;`

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` expects a regex, where `|` has a special meaning and you need to escape it.

```
string.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `|` metacharacter:

```
string.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper escaping: `string.split("\\|")` or the helper function which has been created for exactly this purpose: `string.split(Regexp.quote("|"))`